# Python cannot find the string in csv file

Tags: python, csv, match

I was try to learn how to find a string or value in csv using python. i was think it's simple but when i was try to execute my code, i don't understand why my code cannot find the string what i want. This is my code :

```
import csv

with open('sample2.csv', 'rt') as baca:
    read = csv.reader(baca, delimiter='\'')
    for row in read:
        match = row[0]
        if match == "Sample":
            print match
```

And also i was try to print "row[0]" and the result is like this :

```
id      name         number
1       Sample    0123450000007
```

Print a "row" without index :

```
{'id\tname\tnumber': '1\tSample\t0123450000007'}
```

The screenshot :

[image]

Comment: I guess you need `match = row[1]`

Comment: I was try that, but i got error. "list index out of ranger"

Comment: how does your data looks. May be put some sample lines

Comment: I update my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like demilter should be a tab

```
In [9]: import csv
   ...:
   ...: with open('sample2.csv', 'rt') as baca:
   ...:     read = csv.reader(baca, delimiter='\t')
   ...:     for row in read:
   ...:         match = row[1]
   ...:         if match == "Sample":
   ...:             print match
Sample
```

Comment: it's working!! How you do that ? I mean, i was using row[1] but i got the error "list index out of range", can you explaint to me  ??

Comment: the delimiter you had was incorrect so the record was not split into seperate fields and the print row shows that delimiter is `\t`. In my answer I gave `\t`, which means `TAB` as delimiter.

Comment: now,i understand. Thank you so much for your help, @amit.

Comment: @Scarlettstone - glad to help !

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `csv.DictReader` which makes it easier to select the item you want. Assuming your CSV looks like this:

```
id,name,number
1,Sample,234234
2,NotAMatch,567657
```

You can print the matching rows like this:

```
In [159]: import csv
In [160]: with open('samples.csv') as f:
     ...:     reader = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter='\t')
     ...:     for row in reader:
     ...:         if row['name'] == "Sample":
     ...:             print(row)
     ...:             
OrderedDict([('id', '1'), ('name', 'Sample'), ('number', '234234')])
```

Or a little shorter with a list comprehension:

```
In [163]: with open('samples.csv') as f:
     ...:     reader = csv.DictReader(f)
     ...:     print([row for row in reader if row['name'] == "Sample"])
```

Comment: it's still give me error. the error is "Key error : 'name' "

Comment: Post a sample of your CSV including any header row.

Comment: @Scarlettstone look at my updated answer. You just need to change your delimiter to `'\t'`.

Comment: It would be best to post it in text format. LibreOffice doesn't show what the raw formatting of the file looks like. But I'm pretty sure changing the delimiter will solve your problem.